# Simple window animation before index loads

Tags: jquery, html

Before my index page loads i want to pop up a window for the user to choose the prefered language for the website and then click to load for example /english/index.html or /spanish/index.html, any ideas from where i have to start.

Can i use jquery to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `div` tag into your page:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {      
  document.querySelector('a.close').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('language-popup').style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
#language-popup {
  background-color: #AAAAFF;
  font-family: Verdana;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25%;
}

#language-popup h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#language-popup ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#language-popup a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#language-popup a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#language-popup .close {
  float: right;
}

#language-popup .close:hover {  
  text-decoration: none;
}

#language-popup .close:after {
  content: '✖';
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="language-popup">  
  <a class='close'></a>
  <h3>Select your preferred language</h3>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='english/index.html'>English</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='espanol/index.html'>Español</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='portugues/index.html'>Português - BR</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Then, you can improve it to see if the user already has a saved language preference, e.g:

```
var userPreference = localStorage.get('user-language-preference');
if (userPreference) window.location.assign(userPreference);
```

But you must add another javascript into your `(language)/index.html` pages to save them:

```
localStorage.setItem('user-language-preference', window.location.href);
```

Comment: Thank you, very simple and easy way to do it, valeu :)